# Can I use a file based database on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, nedb

I have a small Node.js / Express app deployed to Heroku.

I'd like to use a lightweight database like [NeDB](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb) to persist some data. Is it possible to periodically backup / copy a file from Heroku if I used this approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

File-based databases aren't a good fit for Heroku due to its [ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) (bold added):

> Each dyno gets its own ephemeral filesystem, with a fresh copy of the most recently deployed code. During the dyno’s lifetime its running processes can use the filesystem as a temporary scratchpad, but no files that are written are visible to processes in any other dyno and **any files written will be discarded the moment the dyno is stopped or restarted. For example, this occurs any time a dyno is replaced due to application deployment and approximately once a day as part of normal dyno management.**

Depending on your use case I recommend using a client-server database (this looks like a good fit here) or something like [Amazon S3 for file storage](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3).