# heroku resets the text file in my project every 24 hours

Tags: python, heroku, text, cloud

I published a project in Heroku. The text file in my project is reset every 24 hours, all data in it is lost. How do I solve the problem?

Comment: Maybe because of this? https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use a file based database on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50421061/can-i-use-a-file-based-database-on-heroku)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot.

Heroku Dynos restart every 24 hours and any file change is discarded (see [Heroku ephemeral filesystem](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem))

If you need to persist data you can use a DB (ie Postgres) or a remote storage (ie Amazon S3)

Comment: See some examples at https://github.com/gcatanese/HerokuFiles