# Images erased in Heroku

Tags: image, heroku, deployment, project

A few days ago I started using Heroku to deploy my project but I am having a problem and it is that after a certain period of time the images that I upload to the app are deleted and I do not know how to solve it.
I would like to know if there is any way to configure it or if I would have to use a specific Heroku service.
Currently I put an UPTIME ROBOT to prevent the dynos from sleeping but still it was not solved...
I am waiting for an answer, thank you.

Comment: Heroku has an ephemeral filesystem which means that nothing will ever be guaranteed to be saved. You're better served storing those images in a database and/or on the cloud.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [After git push heroku - uploaded files on Heroku are lost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246736/after-git-push-heroku-uploaded-files-on-heroku-are-lost)

Comment: Maybe this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/65553997/9095551