# The file in Heroku can not be modified

Tags: heroku, python-telegram-bot

I just deploy a python app in a free Heroku server. This python app provides a telegram bot to me. I want the bot to modify the `userconfig.json` which is in the same directory with `main.py`. When I test my bot in my local machine, it works well, the `userconfig.json` can be modified, but when app deploys on Heroku, it can't modify the file. After sending the `modify` order, there is no change on my `userconfig.json`. How can I solve this problem?

Below is the member method which modifies the json file

```
    def  modify_token(self, new_token):
        self.tokenArray[0] = new_token
        token_update = [{'token': self.tokenArray[0]}]
        try:
            with open("./userconfig.json", 'w') as config:
                json.dump(token_update, config)
        except Exception as e:
            return False

        return True
```

And I use these codes to ask telegram bot to modify the file

```
def modify(update: Update, context: CallbackContext):
    # print(context)
    print(context.args)
    try:
        user_cake.modify_token(context.args[0])
    except Exception as e:
        err_res = str(e)
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="An error occurred:" + err_res)
    else:
        context.bot.send_message(chat_id=update.effective_chat.id, text="Your new token is: " + user_cake.tokenArray[0])
```

Comment: Hi. Do you get any error messages? If yes, please share the tracebacks. Can it be a file permisison problem? Can you show the relevant part of your code? Please have a look at [this guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) on how to formulate well-posed questions :)

Comment: This isn't the immediate problem, but you shouldn't be modifying data on the local filesystem. See [Can I use a file based database on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50421061/354577), for example.

Comment: @CallMeStag there are no error messages output and `userconfig.json`have `wirte` permission.

Comment: @Chris You are right, but I'm just curious about why I can't modify my file on heroku but can modify my file on local when the app runs

Comment: @Mike Maybe you just don't see the errors because you `try-except` them away in your `modify_token` function?