# Heroku keeps deleting my chat bot's database, How can I stop it?

Tags: sqlite, heroku, chatbot

I built a telegram chat bot that creates its own database in sqlite3 as it operates. I deployed that bot to Heroku's server but unfortunately whenever I make an update the server replaces the all the old code with the new code. Which also means the bot ends up with no database and creates a new one. How can I get Heroku to recognize the databases my bot builds as a database? Or at least a file it should not alter?

Additional Info
The server automatically deploys changes made to my github. I am using '.gitignore' so git is not the source problem. Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use a file based database on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50421061/can-i-use-a-file-based-database-on-heroku)

Comment: The only option is to use a client-server database like PostgreSQL instead of a file-based database like SQLite.