# How to check database of a deployed flask web app

Tags: heroku, flask-sqlalchemy

I have deployed a Flask web app on Heroku platform.
This app has a functionality of user registrations.
Is there any way I can access the database and check who all have registered on my application?
When I used to run my app on local machine, it used to create a database file, .sqlite file and I could check the user credentials.
How can I do that once the app is deployed ?

Comment: With a file-backed database like SQLite, you can't do this very easily at all. But file-based databases are a bad fit for Heroku anyway due to its ephemeral filesystem. If you switch to a client-server database like PostgreSQL you can simply connect to it and look at the data.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use a file based database on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50421061/can-i-use-a-file-based-database-on-heroku)