# Symfony hosted in heroku with SqlLite error

Tags: sqlite, symfony, heroku

```
Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\MethodNotAllowedHttpException: "No route found for "GET http://task-demi.herokuapp.com/api/register": Method Not Allowed (Allow: POST)" at /app/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/EventListener/RouterListener.php line 140
```

So I have uploaded my Symfony 5 in heroku.
It is working well in localhost,no error ,but after hosting in Heroku I get above error.
I have used SqlLite

```
DATABASE_URL="sqlite:///%kernel.project_dir%/var/data.db"
```

doctrine_heroku.yaml

```
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver: 'pdo_sqlite'
        server_version: '3.15'
```

How to resolve this?

Comment: I don't think this is the cause of the problem you describe here, but [you can't use SQLite on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50421061/354577) unless you're okay frequently losing all your data without notice.

Comment: Actually this is simple project just  to show to recruiters for a moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you install `symfony/apache-pack`. It allows you to access any URL on your application without having to include /index.php in the path.

In order to quickly enable rewriting for the Apache web server, you can install the symfony/apache-pack recipe, which places a suitable .htaccess file into your public/ directory:

```
composer require symfony/apache-pack
git add composer.json composer.lock symfony.lock public/.htaccess
git commit -m "apache-pack"
```

Source : Heroku

Comment: Your solution worked but when I try to login, I get username or password is wrong or when I try to register user as username=admin, password=admin, `The server returned a "500 Internal Server Error".` while fetching items route is working wel..

Comment: Sqlite is not supported by Heroku. You should try another like Postgres