# Heroku regularly self clearing all the data from Strapi

Tags: heroku, strapi

I ran into strange Heroku behavior after I published my backend to Strapi on it.
From time to time (few times during the day), my whole backend data is completely cleared, deleting all posts that I made, as well as all users and permissions.
I have to re-register every time to get access and then manually add all the content once again.

Can you please tell me why is it so, and how to avoid it? I am making no commits during this time.

Comment: I don't know anything about Strapi, but if it saves any date on the local filesystem (e.g. in files or file-based databases like SQLite) you're just running into Heroku's ephemeral filesystem.

Comment: It looks like [Strapi supports a few database servers](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/setup-deployment-guides/installation/cli.html#preparing-the-installation). Which one are you using? Assuming it's SQLite, please see the following proposed duplicate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use a file based database on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50421061/can-i-use-a-file-based-database-on-heroku)

Comment: Dear Chris,
I created AWS S3 bucket, 
provided Public access to everything
set CORS
created a User in IAM
provided him AmazonS3FullAccess
get his Access key ID & Secret key
then in terminal (connected to hiroku) I setup the following: 

heroku config:set AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=*** AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=*** 
heroku config:set S3_BUCKET_NAME=mielenyvin
heroku config:set AWS_URL=https://mielenyvin.s3.amazonaws.com/
heroku config:set AWS_S3_REGION_NAME=us-east-2

But all the posts from my db as well as roles still disappearing. Nothing appearing in my bucket when I am adding a new post.