# File in Heroku app not being appended to?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, heroku, fs

I have a Heroku app of the following structure:

- APP

  - app.js
  - package.json
  - package-lock.json
  - Procfile
  - node_modules
  - data.csv

I'm trying to write to data.csv whenever a specific function is called. Then, I run heroku run bash -a app_name (which I believe shows the app environment). In the bash, when I run 'cat data.csv', the file contents haven't been updated. I'm using the fs module to append to the file, but for some reason it's not working. Any help appreciated:

```
fs.stat('./data.csv', function (err, stat) {
    if (err == null) {
      console.log('File exists');

      //write the actual data and end with newline
      var csv = json2csv(jsonObject) + newLine;

      fs.appendFile('./data.csv', csv, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('The "data to append" was appended to file!');
      });
    } else {
      //write the headers and newline
      console.log('New file, just writing headers');
      fields = fields + newLine;

      fs.writeFile('./data.csv', fields, function (err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log('file saved');
      });
    }
});
```

When I run the function, it prints "The "data to append" was appended to file!", so I know the function is running correctly, but either 1) I'm not accessing the correct file, 2) writes are not persisted after the function ends 3) something else.

Comment: Try to write something to the csv manually and print the content of the csv to make sure the path is correct. Also try to check if the csv has write permission.

Comment: @node_man Read and write permissions when I run ls -l are -rw-r--r-- in the heroku bash and locally. Yes, the manual local start (using node app.js) works fine when I specify ./data.csv. The csv file is included in the git commit, which is then obviously packaged into the app on heroku deployment, not sure why it can't update though...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can I use a file based database on Heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50421061/can-i-use-a-file-based-database-on-heroku)

Comment: Please read the proposed duplicate. You cannot use a file as a database on Heroku. Additionally, `heroku run bash` does not connect to your running dyno: it spins up a one-off dyno that gets discarded as soon as you log off. As a result, even temporary changes to the file made via your web application will not be visible via `heroku run bash`, and vice-versa. You'll need to use a proper client-server data store.